# zend framework action stack help needed

Tags: php, zend-framework, request

I am using `action stack` in my ZF application. I will explain scenario over here. In first action I have simple form with select box and submit button. Now on post I validate data and save and push my second action in `action stack`.

Second action that I pushed in stack is also having a form which will save data on post.

Now the problem occurs here: when action stack gets processed, it pops stack and forwards my second action stored in stack. Now when my second action is called it goes directly to the loop in post and tries to validate data because the first action request was post, and I don't get the form from second action.

I know action stack is evil but as of now I have no other alternative. this is just one scenario i have tried to explain my problem.

I would be glad to explain more in detail if i am not able to explain question properly...

```
public function firstactionAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        //validate and save form
        $helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('actionStack');
        $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
        $request->setControllerName('index');
        $request->setModuleName('default');
        $request->setActionName('secondaction');
        $helper->pushStack($request);
    } else {
        //creating form object and assigning to view.
    }
}
public function secondactionAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        //Problem is here.. when action stack gets processed.. it directly comes here. as it uses forward internally..
    } else {
        //creating form object and assigning to view.
    }
}
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: Why can't you just redirect to the second action?

Comment: @TimFountain : because i dont want user to redirect to that page.. if my secondaction is automated than it will also add something to actionstack and move further automatically..

Comment: have you tried using `_forward()` instead of the action stack. It allows you to forward to another action with doing a redirect.

Comment: @RockyFord action stack internally uses forward..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one easy way: just add a simple hidden field  to each form and do the next condition:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('hidden') == 'second_form') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: by adding this it will work. but suppose if i dont do anything in secondform action and leave the page. and than i again come back to this page by the url directly.. than at that moment i have to again set the hidden element in the form of second action.. so i have to do this in all the actions..

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. i was doing this way only and at this moment now i have add some hidden element to every form..

Comment: i didnt mark it as correct because i am not 100% satisfied with this workaround.. but it fixed my work so cheers to you.. :-)